# Data Retrieval using PHP,Code Not Working

Tags: php, html

I'm Trying to Retrieve Data from a Database using PHP using dropdown,i want to fetch data from a table, but would like to display different id's.
Like id-1 name-apple,id-2 name-samsung.so on.
now when i fetch id-1 using first dropdown it is displayed,on selecting second dropdown first one is erased and result from second drop down is displayed.
i would like to display results independently,ie..first dropdown should display its result separately,second dropdown should display its result separately.both results should be displayed on same page and from same database table.

```html
<?php
  include('code.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> Search  </title>
<style>
    {
        background-color: whitesmoke;
    }
    input
    {
        width: 40%;
        height: 5%;
        border-radius: 05px;
        padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
        margin: 10px,0px,15px,0px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px grey;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <center>
 <h1> Search From Database</h`enter code here`1>

             <form action="" method="post">
             Select Name for Search:
            <select name="id" placeholder="Enter ID to Search"/><br/>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="1" >Hero</option>
            <option value="2">Herione</option>
            <option value="3">Actor</option>
            <option value="4">Actress</option>
             </select><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search Data-1">
        </form>
<br>
<br>
                <?php
                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run))
                      {
                          ?>

                         <form action ="" method="POST">
                         <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']?> "/>
                         <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name']?> "/>
                         <input type="text" name="gender" value="<?php echo $row['gender']?> "/>
                         <input type="text" name="Age" value="<?php echo $row['Age']?> "/>
                         <input type="text" name="Address" value="<?php echo $row['Address']?> "/>
                         </form>
                          <?php

                      } 
 ?>
             <form action="" method="post">
             Select Name for Search:
            <select name="id" placeholder="Enter ID to Search"/><br/>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="1" >Hero</option>
            <option value="2">Herione</option>
            <option value="3">Actor</option>
            <option value="4">Actress</option>
             </select><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search Data-2">
        </form>
<br>
<br>
                  <?php
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run))
                      {
                          ?>
                          <form action ="" method="POST">
                         <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']?> "/>
                         <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name']?> "/>
                         <input type="text" name="gender" value="<?php echo $row['gender']?> "/>
                         <input type="text" name="Age" value="<?php echo $row['Age']?> "/>
                         <input type="text" name="Address" value="<?php echo $row['Address']?> "/>
                         </form>
                          <?php

                       }
 ?>
            </center>
           </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually i did not understand what is your problem so pls show any example you wanted or your expected output

Comment: If you don't want your whole page to be replaced every time you submit either of the forms, then use AJAX to submit each form, and then only update the specific table with the results, rather than refreshing the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

As ADyson said, you need ajax.
Try adapting this example based on your code :

```
<html>

<head>
<title> Search </title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body {
         background-color: whitesmoke;
    }

input {
     width: 40%;
     height: 5%;
     border-radius: 05px;
     padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
     margin: 10px, 0px, 15px, 0px;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px grey;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
      <form action="" method="post">
            Select Name for Search:
            <select name="id" id="select-search-1" placeholder="Enter ID to Search" /><br />
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="1">Hero</option>
            <option value="2">Herione</option>
            <option value="3">Actor</option>
            <option value="4">Actress</option>
            </select><br />
            <input type="button" class="search" name="search1" id="search-1" value="Search Data-1">
        </form>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="form-search-1">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="id" value="id" />
                <input type="text" name="name" value="name" />
                <input type="text" name="gender" value="gender" />
                <input type="text" name="Age" value="Age" />
                <input type="text" name="Address" value="Address" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <form action="" method="post">
            Select Name for Search:
            <select name="id" id="select-search-2" placeholder="Enter ID to Search" /><br />
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="1">Hero</option>
            <option value="2">Herione</option>
            <option value="3">Actor</option>
            <option value="4">Actress</option>
            </select><br />
            <input type="button" name="search2" class="search" id="search-2" value="Search Data-2">
        </form>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="form-search-2">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="id" value="id" />
                <input type="text" name="name" value="name" />
                <input type="text" name="gender" value="gender" />
                <input type="text" name="Age" value="Age" />
                <input type="text" name="Address" value="Address" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>

</html>
<script>
    $(".search").on('click', function(e) {

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var combo = 'select-' + id;
    var id_combo = $('#' + combo).val();

    $.post("ajax_get_data.php", {

            "id_combo": id_combo

        },
        function(data) {
            $('#form-' + id).html(data);
        });

    });
</script>
```

With this you call the php script (ajax_get_data.php) that performs the query and builds the requested form with the data obtained.

And ajax_get_data.php :

```
<?php

    $id = $_POST['id_combo'];

    $sql = 'your qry with $id value';

    // harcoded values for the example, replace with that obtained from qry
    $row = ['id'=>'id-'.$id, 'name'=>'name-'.$id, 'gender'=>'gender-'.$id, 
   'Age'=>'Age-'.$id, 'Address'=>'Address-' . $id];

    echo '<form action="" method="POST">
              <input type="text" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'" />
              <input type="text" name="name" value="'.$row['name'].'" />
              <input type="text" name="gender" value="'.$row['gender'].'" />
              <input type="text" name="Age" value="'.$row['Age'].'" />
              <input type="text" name="Address" value="'.$row['Address'].'" />
          </form>
            
       ';
```